# Is there any Hindu sect which considers Lord Hanuman as Supreme Brahman?

Tags: hanuman, sects

I would like to know if there are any sects like Vaishnavas,Shaivas or Shaktas who consider Lord Hanuman as the Supreme God(Brahman). Not including smartha sect which considers all Gods as Supreme.

Comment: Lord Hanuman is always shown as serving another deity, sitting at the feet of the deity then how is it possible to consider him as supreme? Even before you start worshiping Lord Hanuman you need to first pray to Lord Rama.

Comment: But according to astrology he is an Ishta Devata. So, there will be many people whose Ishta Dev will be Lord Hanuman.

Comment: Rickross said what I was thinking. He is venerated for his devotion to Rama, not his devotion to himself. I'm not even sure how to give this a proper answer as the answer comes from logic, which is not a valid source on this SE.

Comment: @Rickross well I think Lord Hanuman is mostly seen serving Lord Rama. But there are various shrines where only Lord Hanuman is worshipped alone. In my city there is a very popular temple where Lord Hanuman is worshipped in Panchmukhi(five faced) roopa. Infact almost every where in North India and Mauritius have a small Lord Hanuman right intront of houses etc. That's very common even in villages

Comment: @Rickross i know as one astrologer told me that Lord Hanuman is my ishta deva.

Comment: Okay good .. @RishX

Comment: Actually many people I know have Hanuman as Ishta .. but I don't think it bothers them at all whether he can be regarded as supreme or not.@RishX

Comment: Original version of Ramayana, sans interpolations, did present Sri Hanuman as the Jnani , with super human powers.  If we closely observe his activities, we can find striking similarities between him and Sri Krishna.  In esoteric sense, a Jnani, a SELF REALISED one, is a BRAHMAN. @RishX

Comment: @Rickross then they might be Advaitins or Smartha. What I want to know of there is a separate sect of Hindus who worship Lord Hanuman as supreme like we have Ganpataya for Lord Ganesha worshippers. From what I could gather, Lord Hanuman worship from  North India is primarily due to Ramanandi Sampradaya,A Vaishnava sampradaya which revers Lord Rama as Supreme. Even Tulasidas who wrote Ramcharitmanas,Hanuman Chalisa and Hanuman Ashtak,was a Ramanandi Vaishnava.

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV what do u mean by super powers? Siddhis? And what you said about  self realized one being Brahman is Advaita perspective. While most North Indian Hanuman Worship has evolved from Ramanandi Vaishnavism.

Comment: @RishX: I don't know anything about Ramanandi Vaishnavism, so I do not want to make comment on why they think so.  My perspective is from Valmiki's Ramayana.  The present version of Valmiki's Ramayana contains interpolated stories, eulogising Sri Rama as the incarnation of Vishnu, which is not in the original version.  Yes, I am talking about Siddhis of Sri Hanuman